# C++ how to overload method using pass by value and pass by reference

Tags: c++, overloading

How do I make the following overload work

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int subtractFive (int a)
{
    a = a - 5;

    return a;
}

int subtractFive (int &a)
{
    a = a -5;

    return a -5;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 10;

    cout << "Answer: " << subtractFive(*A) << endl;
    cout << "A Value "<< A << endl;

    cout << "Answer: " << subtractFive(A) << endl;
    cout << "A Value "<< A << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Tried but doesnt compile

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int subtractFive (int a)
{
    a = a - 5;

    return a;
}

void subtractFive (int* a)
{
    *a = *a -5;
}

int main()
{
    int A = 10;

    cout << "Answer: " << subtractFive(A) << endl;
    cout << "A Value "<< A << endl;

    subtractFive(A);
    cout << "A Value "<< A << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I want to to make a subract function that takes both an address and another subtract that takes the value

Comment: What is `*A` supposed to do?

Comment: @stackoverflow: What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: that was intential to point out to anyone that I want to use the function that accepts the &a

Comment: You realize that the second subtractFive function `int subtractFive (int &a){a = a -5;return a -5;}`will actually return a - 10 if it did work?

Answer (score 0):

You might try specifying an overload that takes an address as an argument:

```
int subtractFive (int *a)
{
    *a = *a -5;

    return *a -5;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare one function as pass by **address** the other by value or reference:

```
void subtractByFive(int * p_value)
{
    if (p_value != NULL)
    {
       *p_value -= 5;
    }
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A value and a reference have the same type so you can't overload on it. If you want two functions one of which modifies its parameter and one that returns the new value then you either have to give them different names or different types (e.g. make the latter function use a pointer type).